# Android Wear Message API Encoding and Decoding Byte[]

Tags: android, arrays, wear-os

I've written a simple app the uses the Android Wear Messaging API. I followed a number of guides that all use a similar style of code for sending the message with some data which should be in byte[] form.

The code sending the message is

```
Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(client, nodeId, message, "test".getBytes());
```

and the receiving code is

```
final String messageData = new String(messageEvent.getData());
```

This seems to fit with a number of different guides and some of the official documentation - however the variable `messageData` ends up containing `[B@4b0ad22` rather than `test` which is the data that was sent.

I've also tried explicit encoding/decoding with

```
String messageData = new String(messageEvent.getData(), "UTF-8");
```

but that throws a `java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException`

What's going wrong with the encoding or decoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the encoding/decoding but also wrap it in a try/catch block so the receiving code looks like this,

```
    String messageData = "";
    try {


        messageData = new String(messageEvent.getData(), "UTF-8");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DecodingError", e.toString());
    }
```

The sending code looks like this;

```
        try {
            Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(client, nodeId, message, "test".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("EncodingError", e.toString());
        }
```